# Using built-in screen capture functions in OSX and receive output?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

As most advanced mac users know there is a simple way to take a screenshot. Just using command-shift-4 to take part of a screen as an example. But is there a possibility to use this functionality from say, a python script?

I've seen other threads about taking a screen capture from python (or other languages) but is there any way to use the built in functionality from a script and then use the output as you will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the terminal command `screencapture`

This can be invoked from a python script (or other script):

```
import os;
os.system("screencapture /tmp/test.jpg");
#### do your stuff with the file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't know it existed! :)

Comment: no problem. added python code, but maybe in your case a bash script will be right choice of language.

Comment: Actually, it's much better to use the terminal command for the application I'm making. You get so much for free ;)